# Linear Regression with a known fixed intercept in Accord.NET

Tags: vb.net, linear-regression, accord.net

I use Accord.NET for calculating slope and intercept of linear regression based on this page http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Models_Regression_Linear_SimpleLinearRegression.htm

I want to set a fixed interception value so that Accord will predict the slope only. Can I do that thing in Accord.NET?

```
Dim inp(10), opt(10) As Double
inp = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
opt = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}

Dim ols As New OrdinaryLeastSquares
Dim reg As New SimpleLinearRegression

reg.Intercept = 4 'no effect, how can we set the intercept value?
reg = ols.Learn(inp, opt)

Dim hsl As String
hsl = "y=" + reg.Slope.ToString + "X+" + reg.Intercept.ToString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `ols.UseIntercept = False`, add the desired intercept value to each `opt` value, and run `ols.Learn()`. The resulting `Slope` will be calculated for the intercept you want.

Comment: Thank you @RobertBaron, that's work for my case. previously, I didn't know how to add the desired intercept value. thanks a lot for your solution.

Comment: @taufiq yuliawan - You are welcome! Glad I could help!